# Does "proposer" require subjunctive in a clause begins with "avec"

Tags: subjonctif

I was reading this sentence and wondered why **permette** there isn't simply **permet**

> Nous proposons des robes, avec le détail mode qui leur **permette** de passer les saisons.

I do understand that **proposer** does require a subjunctive in a subordinating sentence like:

> Je propose qu'on fasse une pause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right. The correct sentence is indeed:

> Nous proposons des robes, avec le détail mode qui leur permet de passer les saisons.

Answer (score 2):

Just for extra context, this is a specialized use of "proposer": in commercial/sales situations, it means "offer X as a product".

I agree with Jiliagre here, this is just some copywriter who overextended the subjunctive. A factor at play is probably that people tend to associate the subjunctive with an elevated style of speech, which is what one might find in what sounds here like a catalogue or other sales document.